# Parametric vs Non-parametric data?

Tags: interpretation, nonparametric, terminology

Today I have been asked question the difference between parametric data and non-parametric data. I know about parametric and non-parametric statistics, parametric and non-parametric test, but I have never heard about parametric data. I have also not studied this term in any statistics book.

On internet, I just managed to find one blog that mentioned parametric and non-parametric data. Checked link:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-nonparametric-statistics/

I just wanted to know, are these legal words in statistics or just coined by the author to explain parametric and non-parametric test?

Comment: People use that term to refer to non-normal data for which nonparametric tests may be more suitable, but it’s a bit of a silly term.

Comment: @Dave Is this a formal word? Any reference of text book?

Comment: Absence here is more evocative than presence. If you find a textbook that talks about non-parametric data, it's either a typo or a sign of incompetence. As non-parametric methods can be applied to any kind of data, those non-parametric methods, which predominantly means non-parametric significance tests, do not even define the data they are applied to.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no such thing as parametric data or non-parametric data**. (As already mentioned in comments.) The terms *parametric* and *non-parametric* describes **methods** or **models**, not data.  See some earlier questions about that:

- [What exactly is the difference between a parametric and non-parametric model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268638/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-a-parametric-and-non-parametric-model)
- [Parametric vs. Nonparametric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50141/parametric-vs-nonparametric)
- [What are the differences between parametric and non-parametric statistical tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218003/what-are-the-differences-between-parametric-and-non-parametric-statistical-tests)
- [What are real life examples of "non-parametric statistical models"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230044/what-are-real-life-examples-of-non-parametric-statistical-models)

(and others you find by searching this site.)